# kendo Grid bind error on custom

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

currently i am working on kendo Grid. I am facing this error. please help me to solve this error.

> 'DataSourceBuilder' does not contain a definition for
>   'Custom' and no extension method 'Custom' accepting a first argument
>   of type 'DataSourceBuilder' could be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)

my code is on razor view is as following:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoApp.Models.Customer>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ID)
                .ClientFooterTemplate("<div>Total Count: #=count#</div><div>Min: #= min #</div><div>Max: #= max #</div>");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Age)
            .ClientFooterTemplate("Average: #=average#");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name)
            .ClientFooterTemplate("<div>Count: #= count #</div>");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Salary)
            .ClientFooterTemplate("<div>Sum: #= sum #</div>");
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Create();
        toolbar.Save();
    })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .Pageable()
    .Navigatable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Custom()
        .Batch(true)
        .PageSize(20)
        .Schema(schema => schema.Model(m => m.Id(p => p.ProductID)))
        .Transport(transport =>
        {
            transport.Read(read =>
            read.Url("http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products")
                .DataType("jsonp")
            );
            transport.Create(create =>
            create.Url("http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products/create")
                    .DataType("jsonp")
            );
            transport.Update(update =>
            update.Url("http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products/update")
                    .DataType("jsonp")
            );
            transport.Destroy(destroy =>
            destroy.Url("http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products/destroy")
                    .DataType("jsonp")
            );
            transport.ParameterMap("parameterMap");
        })
    )
)
```

Error display on "custom". please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom DataSource was introduced in version **2014.1.318**. Make sure you are using this or a newer **Kendo.Mvc.dll** version than that.

More information on custom DataSource usage is available at:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/custom-datasource